# How do I calculate the following probability?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

Let's say there are 5 cats and 20 dogs and you get a random group of 2 animals. What is the probability that you end up with a dog and a cat? All possible combinations where you get a cat and a dog are $5\cdot20$ and all possible combinations are $C_{25}^2=\frac{25\cdot24}{2!}$ so $P(\text{a cat and a dog})=\frac{5\cdot20\cdot2!}{25\cdot24}=\frac{1}{3}$. However my textbook says the probability is actually $\frac{1}{6}$ and i can't figure out why. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is correct.  The probability of selecting a cat and a dog when two of the $25$ animals are selected at random is
$$\Pr(\text{a cat and a dog}) = \frac{\dbinom{5}{1}\dbinom{20}{1}}{\dbinom{25}{2}} = \frac{1}{3}$$

The probability of selecting a dog and a cat in that order is
$$\Pr(\text{dog then a cat}) = \frac{20}{25} \cdot \frac{5}{24} = \frac{1}{6}$$
However, the way the problem is worded, you would also have to consider the probability of selecting a cat and a dog in that order, which is
$$\Pr(\text{cat then a dog}) = \frac{5}{25} \cdot \frac{20}{24} = \frac{1}{6}$$
Adding those two probabilities gives your correct answer.